# Add query string to data-href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, facebook

I want to add a string after an url inside data-href using jQuery. I want to make sure that my Facebook comments plugin creates a separate thread for each page that loads the comments plugin.

What should be added after the data-href url is `?st=<?php echo $post->post_name;?>` - but not sure how to implement this in PHP from WordPress into a jQuery code.

right now:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://myurl.com" data-width="100%" data-numposts="3" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

what it should look like with `post_slug` being the slug that WordPress creates for each individual post.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://myurl.com/?st=post_slug" data-width="100%" data-numposts="3" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have jQuery in your page then you can use this script block:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.fb-comments').each(function(){ // loop if there are more blocks
           var oldDataHref = $(this).data('href'); // get the data-href of current "fb-comments"
           var newDataHref = oldDataHref + '?st=<?php echo $post->post_name;?>'; // make a new data-href
           $(this).attr('data-href', newDataHref); // set the data-href here.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code, it looks very logical and clean... But the url in data-href still remains the original link for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: @meight08 `$(this).attr('data-href', newDataHref);` use this line.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Select all elements. It seems they are multiple.
var elems = $('fb-comments'); 

// Get first or you can iterate over above array.
var elem = elems[0];

// Append whatever text you want.
//    `$(elem).data('href')` gets current value.
//    `$(elem).data('href', 'new_val')` sets current value.
$(elem).data('href', $(elem).data('href') + '?st=<?php echo $post->post_name;?>');
```

Comment: Can you describe your solution please?

Comment: @Stephan added comments

Answer (score 0):

Get the link

```
var link = document.document.getElementById("fb-comments");
```

Change the attribute

```
link.setAttribute('data-href', "new one");
```

You can use [getAttribute()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) to get the original and edit it.
**Change the "class" to "id" in your html.**

Comment: Does it not matter that I'm trying to target **data**-href and not just href? Not an expert with jQuery, but I added this above the fb-comments div

    <script>
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fb-comments");
link.setAttribute('href', "https://myurl.com/?st=ind");
</script>

Wasn't sure how to use getAttribute() in here.

Comment: Sorry, yes you need to use the attribute name you need. And the get one will give you the original value which you can edit with some string operations like concat().

Comment: Unfortunately the data-href url remains the original one :(

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
var str = "new url";

$(".fb-comments").prop("data-href",str);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `json_encode` — this returns the JSON representation of a value. You then can manipulate the data-href with the jQuery.

example below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      // convert the value
      var value = <?php echo json_encode($post->post_name); ?>
      // get the existing value of data-href
      var href = $('.fb-comments').attr('data-href');
      // create new link with extending php value 
      var newLink = href + '?st=' + value;
      // change the data-href value
      $(".fb-comments").attr('data-href',encodeURIComponent(newLink));
    });
```